# How can I display data in table with Perl?

Tags: perl, html-table

I am getting data from a database.  It has 4 rows and 6 columns. I want to show this in an HTML table but am having problems.  I've made the TH for the 6 columns.  However, I am having problems in displaying the 4 rows.  This is what I have so far:

```
while (($f1, $t2, $n3, $k4, $d5, $e6) = $sth1->fetchrow_array)
{
        push (@first, $f1);
        push (@second, $t2);
        push (@third, $n3);
        push (@fourth, $k4);
        push (@fifth, $d5);
        push (@sixth, $e6);
}
```

@first, @second...and others are arrays

While dsplaying data if I do:

```
foreach (@first)
{
        print "<td>$_</td>";
}
```

That is displaying data vertically but I want it to display horizontally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in the question is written using Perl's DBI (DataBase Interface):

```
print "<table>\n";
while (($f1, $t2, $n3, $k4, $d5, $e6) = $sth1->fetchrow_array)
{
    print "  <tr>\n";
    print "    <td>$f1</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$t2</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$n3</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$k4</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$d5</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$e6</td>\n";
    print " </tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```

Or you could read the row into an array and then print the array more succinctly:

```
print "<table>\n";
while (my(@row) = $sth1->fetchrow_array)
{
    print "  <tr>\n";
    print "    <td>$val</td>\n" foreach my $val (@row);
    print " </tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also use [HTML::Table](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Table/lib/HTML/Table.pm).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Table;

my $table = HTML::Table->new( 
    -cols    => 6, 
    -border  => 1,
    -padding => 1,
    -head => [qw( f1 t2 n3 k4 d5 e6 )],
);

# do query here.    

while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    $table->addRow(@row);
}

$table->print;
```

Comment: @Jill448, you need to do the database query and and get a statement handle, `$sth`.  That code needs to be in the `#do query here` section.  You'll also need to add load the DBI.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a little more flexibility without having to write as much code, you might also want to check out HTML::Table::FromDatabase. It does the HTML for you and gives you the freedom to format things easily. It takes a little practice, but it has become an invaluable took in my arsenal.

Here is some sample code that will give you an idea of what you can do with it

```
use DBI;
use HTML::Table::FromDatabase;
use HTML::Table;
use CGI;

# Start the CGI wrapper
$query = new CGI();

# Just build the STH like normal, with either the SQL in-line or an $sql variable
my $sth = $mysql_dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2 FROM table ORDER BY field1");
$sth->execute;

# Tell the module to build the table using the STH you executed before
my $table = HTML::Table::FromDatabase->new(-sth=>$sth,
                                           -border=>1,  # We want a border on the entire table
                                           -callbacks=>[
                                                {
                                                        # On the switch column, we want to add an HREF with the data in the URL
                                                        column=>'field1',
                                                        transform=>
                                                                sub { $_ = shift; qq[<A HREF="$_">$_</A>]; },
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        # This example lets you return a value based on what value is in the field
                                                        column=>'field2',
                                                        transform=>
                                                                sub { $text = shift; DidItMatch($text); },
                                                }],
                                           # The two rows below are used to set CSS classes on even and odd rows if you want different formatting
                                           -evenrowclass=>'evenrow',
                                           -oddrowclass=>'oddrow'
                                           );

# Take the entire table and align all of the 2nd column to center
$table->setColAlign(2,'center');

# The following lines are just demonstrations of what else can be changed. There are a lot, so look at HTML::Table to get all of them
#$table->setColBGColor(2,'red');                # Sets the background color of all cells in a column
#$table->SetColVAlign(2,'middle');              # Sets the vertical alignment of all cells in a column
#$table->setColWidth(2,100);                    # Sets the width of a column. Could also use setColWidth(2,'50%');
#$table->setColNoWrap(2,1);                     # Sets the no-wrap property of a colum. 0=Wrap 1=NoWrap

# The following lines allow you to retrieve information about the table that was created.
my $row_count = $table->getTableRows;          # Retrieves the number of rows in the table
my $column_count = $table->getTableCols;       # Retrieves the number of columns in the table

# Finally, print the finalized table HTML
$table->print;

# Wrap up the STH and DBH if needed
$sth->finish;
$mysql_dbh->disconnect;


sub DidItMatch
{
        my $text = shift;
        if ($text eq 'Good text')
        {
                return "Matched";
        } else
        {
                return "$text";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this closer to what you are trying to achieve?

```
# display one HTML table row for each DB row
print "<table>\n";
while (my @row = $sth1->fetchrow_array) {
  print "<tr>".join("", map { "<td>${_}</td>" } @row)."</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```